# first person movement in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm petty new to unity and need to know how to make my player move in the way it's looking using this code

For example: I want it to move in the way that my player camera is facing when I press w

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float speed;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            Vector3 input2 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + input2 * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            Vector3 input3 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + input3 * speed * Time.deltaTime * -1);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            Vector3 input1 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + input1 * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to unity, I would recommend you to watch Brackeys tutorial on player movement. It gives a detailed answer to your question.

First person: https://youtu.be/_QajrabyTJc

Third person: https://youtu.be/4HpC--2iowE